# Debian SFTP WinSCP “Authentication failed.” User in Group can't establish SFTP connection

Tags: debian, ssh, authentication, sftp

Good evening, world. Neither my English nor my ssh skills are very good. Let's try anyway:

My goal is to create a user who is restricted to his home directory and able to establish an SFTP connection to my host on **5.45.104.48**

- Created a group '**sftp**'
- Added user '**spielergemeinde**' to group
- Home folder is set to /var/www/**spielergemein.de**
- added the following to /etc/ssd/sshd_config :

> Match Group sftp
>
> ChrootDirectory %h
>
> ForceCommand internal-sftp
>
> AllowTcpForwarding no

- **spielergemeinde** is owner of /var/www/**spielergemein.de**
- Password for **spielergemeinde** is alpha-numeric
- restarted and reloaded **service ssh**
- tried to connect:

WinSCP-Log:

```
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.390 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.390 WinSCP Version 5.9.6 (Build 7601) (OS 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 - Windows 7 Ultimate)
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.390 Configuration: HKCU\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.390 Log level: Debug 2
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.390 Local account: noxgandhipc\noxgandhi
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.390 Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.390 Process ID: 6912
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Command-line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" 
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Time zone: Current: GMT+2, Standard: GMT+1 (W. Europe Standard Time), DST: GMT+2 (W. Europe Daylight Time), DST Start: 26.03.2017, DST End: 29.10.2017
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Login time: Donnerstag, 27. Juli 2017 00:12:11
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Session name: spielergemeinde@5.45.104.48 (Site)
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Host name: 5.45.104.48 (Port: 22)
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 User name: spielergemeinde (Password: Yes, Key file: No, Passphrase: No)
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Tunnel: No
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Transfer Protocol: SFTP (SCP)
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Ping type: Off, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Disable Nagle: No
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Proxy: None
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Send buffer: 262144
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 SSH protocol version: 2; Compression: No
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Bypass authentication: No
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Try agent: Yes; Agent forwarding: No; TIS/CryptoCard: No; KI: Yes; GSSAPI: No
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Ciphers: aes,chacha20,blowfish,3des,WARN,arcfour,des; Ssh2DES: No
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 KEX: ecdh,dh-gex-sha1,dh-group14-sha1,rsa,WARN,dh-group1-sha1
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 SSH Bugs: Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Simple channel: Yes
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Return code variable: Autodetect; Lookup user groups: Auto
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Shell: default
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 EOL: LF, UTF: Auto
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Clear aliases: Yes, Unset nat.vars: Yes, Resolve symlinks: Yes; Follow directory symlinks: No
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 LS: ls -la, Ign LS warn: Yes, Scp1 Comp: No
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 SFTP Bugs: Auto,Auto
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 SFTP Server: default
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Local directory: H:\Web\rs3202.isp-network.eu, Remote directory: /, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.394 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.395 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path: 
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.395 DST mode: Unix
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.395 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.455 Looking up host "5.45.104.48" for SSH connection
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.455 Connecting to 5.45.104.48 port 22
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.472 Selecting events 63 for socket 1288
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.472 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.9.6
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.508 Waiting for the server to continue with the initialization
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.508 Looking for incoming data
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.508 Looking for network events
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.508 Detected network event
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.508 Enumerating network events for socket 1288
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.508 Enumerated 19 network events making 19 cumulative events for socket 1288
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.508 Handling network read event on socket 1288 with error 0
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.508 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.508 We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.508 Using SSH protocol version 2
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.508 Have a known host key of type ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.508 Handling network write event on socket 1288 with error 0
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.509 Handling network connect event on socket 1288 with error 0
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.509 Waiting for the server to continue with the initialization
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.509 Looking for incoming data
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.509 Looking for network events
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.532 Detected network event
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.532 Enumerating network events for socket 1288
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.532 Enumerated 1 network events making 1 cumulative events for socket 1288
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.532 Handling network read event on socket 1288 with error 0
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.532 Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.554 Waiting for the server to continue with the initialization
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.554 Looking for incoming data
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.554 Looking for network events
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.575 Detected network event
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.575 Enumerating network events for socket 1288
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.575 Enumerated 1 network events making 1 cumulative events for socket 1288
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.575 Handling network read event on socket 1288 with error 0
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.621 Server also has ssh-dss/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.622 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.622 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 256 a4:f3:3b:05:6f:91:64:e2:df:1b:71:b5:0b:10:87:ee
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.622 Verifying host key ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 nistp256,0x9531c9d7052027d1 7b23cd40db494b0d 6bec24e7785532fe 38572b5b3a242853 ,0x89fa4e763ee38d95 70768b5f6f329020 68a69e6d6cf58eb7 cf5998599552e2d4  with fingerprint ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 256 a4:f3:3b:05:6f:91:64:e2:df:1b:71:b5:0b:10:87:ee
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.669 Host key matches cached key
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.669 Selecting events 63 for socket 1288
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.669 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.669 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.669 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.669 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.669 Waiting for the server to continue with the initialization
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.669 Looking for incoming data
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.669 Looking for network events
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.741 Detected network event
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.741 Enumerating network events for socket 1288
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.741 Enumerated 1 network events making 1 cumulative events for socket 1288
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.741 Handling network read event on socket 1288 with error 0
! 2017-07-27 00:12:11.741 Using username "spielergemeinde".
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.772 Waiting for the server to continue with the initialization
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.772 Looking for incoming data
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.772 Looking for network events
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.791 Detected network event
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.791 Enumerating network events for socket 1288
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.791 Enumerated 1 network events making 1 cumulative events for socket 1288
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.791 Handling network read event on socket 1288 with error 0
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.791 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey,password
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.792 Prompt (password, "SSH password", <no instructions>, "&Password: ")
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.792 Using stored password.
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.826 Sent password
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.826 Waiting for the server to continue with the initialization
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.826 Looking for incoming data
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.826 Looking for network events
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.861 Detected network event
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.861 Enumerating network events for socket 1288
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.861 Enumerated 1 network events making 1 cumulative events for socket 1288
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.861 Handling network read event on socket 1288 with error 0
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.861 Access granted
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.861 Opening session as main channel
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.861 Waiting for the server to continue with the initialization
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.861 Looking for incoming data
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.861 Looking for network events
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.919 Detected network event
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.919 Enumerating network events for socket 1288
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.919 Enumerated 32 network events making 32 cumulative events for socket 1288
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.919 Handling network close event on socket 1288 with error 10053
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.919 Selecting events 0 for socket 1288
. 2017-07-27 00:12:11.919 Network error: Software caused connection abort
* 2017-07-27 00:12:11.942 (EFatal) Network error: Software caused connection abort
* 2017-07-27 00:12:11.942 Authentication log (see session log for details):
* 2017-07-27 00:12:11.942 Using username "spielergemeinde".
* 2017-07-27 00:12:11.943 
* 2017-07-27 00:12:11.943 Authentication failed.
```